# How to open a file with utf-8 non encoded characters?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to open a text file (.dat) in python and I get the following error: 
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 4484: invalid start byte
but the file is encoded using utf-8, so maybe there some character that cannot be read. I am wondering, is there a way to handle the problem without calling each single weird characters? Cause I have a rather huge text file and it would take me hours to run find the non encoded Utf-8 encoded character.

Here is my code

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('compounds.dat', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    if "InChI=1S/C11H8O3/c1-6-5-9(13)10-7(11(6)14)3-2-4-8(10)12/h2-5" in line:
        print(line)
searchfile.close()
```

Comment: Yes, but I think it is just the first non encoded UTF-8 character that encounters in the file, therefore I assume that once I correct for that one I will run into another one and another one and so on. As I specified in the question, the text file I want to read is rather huge

Comment: Side-note: If you're using Python 2.6 or higher, with a standard (bytes->text) codec, don't use `codecs.open`, use `io.open`, which is faster, and less buggy than `codecs.open`. `io.open` is actually the same as the built-in `open` on Python 3, but made available on Python 2 to ease writing Unicode friendly code and simplify porting to Py3.

Comment: Seems to me like "utf-8 non encoded characters" is an [oxymoron](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/oxymoron). To be utf-8 its contents would need to be encoded that way. Perhaps it's `'latin1'`.

Comment: A file that was encoded using UTF-8 _cannot_ contain invalid bytes unless it got corrupted, or the encoder is buggy. I guess either of those things are possible, but it's more likely that the file was not actually encoded as UTF-8, but as something else, eg cp1252. What makes you certain that it's UTF-8?

Comment: FWIW, in cp1252 `0x92` is the encoding of the apostrophe `’`

Comment: @PM2Ring: DAMN YOU SMART-QUOTES! :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It shouldn't "take you hours" to find the bad byte. The error tells you *exactly* where it is; it's at index 4484 in your input with a value of `0x92`; if you did:

```
with open('compounds.dat', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

the invalid byte would be at `data[4484]`, and you can slice as you like to figure out what's around it.

In any event, if you just want to ignore or replace invalid bytes, that's what the `errors` parameter is for. [Using `io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) (because `codecs.open` is subtly broken in many ways, and `io.open` is both faster and more correct):

```
# If this is Py3, you don't even need the import, just use plain open which is
# an alias for io.open
import io

with io.open('compounds.dat', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    for line in f:
        if u"InChI=1S/C11H8O3/c1-6-5-9(13)10-7(11(6)14)3-2-4-8(10)12/h2-5" in line:
            print(line)
```

will just ignore the invalid bytes (dropping them as if they never existed). You can also pass `errors='replace'` to insert a replacement character for each garbage byte, so you're not silently dropping data.

In this case, `0x92` is the cp1252 encoding of `’`, so your file is likely cp1252, and ignoring errors is the wrong solution, you should just use the proper encoding, changing the `with` statement to:

```
with io.open('compounds.dat', encoding='cp1252') as f:
```

Comment: In the vast majoirity of cases, the OP should understand what is really wrong rather than discard the parts they don't understand. Python is doing you a favor by throwing an error when you are probably doing something wrong. (In other words, _blindly_ changing the encoding to e.g. `cp1252` is also wrong, and will produce [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) if that isn't really the correct encoding.)

Comment: @tripleee: Agreed. The fact that the erroring character is a common auto-replace performed by Windows tools make cp1252 *likely*, but it's not guaranteed. For ASCII supersets (aside from the self-checking UTF-8), you just need to *know* what locale was used to make the file, or manually inspect the result, to be sure you picked the right encoding.

Comment: [The Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) has some additional resources for figuring these things out.

Answer (score 2):

if working with huge data , better to use encoding as default and if the error persists then use errors="ignore" as well

```
with open("filename" , 'r'  , encoding="utf-8",errors="ignore") as f:
    f.read()
```